# как запретить масштабирование в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Создаю нечто подобное [этому](https://patterninja.com/) , только с элементом canvas.
В примере каким-то образом отключено масштабирование браузера, кто знает, как это сделать?

Comment: у меня работает

Comment: Благодаря комментарию выше от @Hipster осозрел куда копнуть за ответами в исходнике, а там банльный e.preventDefault(); спасибо тебе, добрый человек

Comment: Дак масштабирование работает по приведенной ссылке, вам же не нужно, чтобы оно работало. Или вы, чего-то недоговариваете. - попробуйте воспользоваться `background-size:cover;` и  `position:fixed;` - должно помочь.

Comment: в хроме работает только если навести мышкой на панель управления, в остальных случаях - нет

Comment: @RysinskyValentine у меня оно работает всюду...

Answer (score -1):

Кароче, все очень просто и банально оказалось

```
function document_wheel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    if ('onwheel' in document) {
        // IE9+, FF17+, Ch31+
        document.addEventListener("wheel", document_wheel);
    } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
        // устаревший вариант события
        document.addEventListener("mousewheel", document_wheel);
    } else {
        // Firefox < 17
        document.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", document_wheel);
    }
} else { // IE8-
    document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", document_wheel);
}
```

для того, что-бы убрать масштабирование комбинациями клавиш:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    },
    false);
```

Comment: И толку, все равно будет работать. Никто не отменял `keyboard events`.

Comment: @And , ну тут тоже есть решение  window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); },
    false);

Comment: В вашем случае, я бы смотрел в сторону `window.onresize` и `window.devicePixelRatio`